# What's responsible for Dash Online lookups? -- I want to uninstall it

Tags: unity, unity-dash

To ensure privacy/security of my data & searches, I don't feel it's adequate to just disable online lookups. I prefer to uninstall whatever provides this functionality.

Is there something (like a package/s) I can uninstall to disable/prevent all online lookups when using the Dash?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is anything to uninstall, but I think that this maybe something that might help.  Open system setting and click on Privacy, once open you can Turn Online Searches On of Off.  See images below.

[image]
[image]